# Trying to find way to animate Array with Random Per Island texture

Tags: animation, materials, modifiers

I have a set of 7 'stones' that's placed in circular way by using Array modifier.[image: Set up]

Here is the material node for it, I've used Random Per Island to give it some variation.[image: Material node]

I'm trying to animate so that each stone fall in to place sequentially (1st from outer ring, then inner, inner, inner etc.) from outside the frame.

I tried using animation node watching a Youtube tutorial but it's shows the Array modifier must be 'applied' and must separate the stones by loose part. This causes the 1 color to be assigned to the original object 1 color to the rest of the pieces.
[image: Material after separation]

How do I solve this?